# How can I get Interim report when test failed and I wish to continue test in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I use robot framework at following environment.

- Python 2.7.6
- robotframework 2.8.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I make directory like followings,
and execute robot like this to get report in TestPTX units.

```
TestCaseRoot
 L TestPT1
    L test_1.robot
    L test_2.robot
    L test_3.robot
 L TestPT2
    L test_a.robot
    L test_b.robot
```

`$ pybot -L TRACE -b debug.log --outputdir <LOG_DIR> TestPT1/`

In this case, test_1,test_2,test_3 are executed and report and log file is included one file.

But when test_2 were failed , pybot continue to execute test_3, and until test_3 were done report were not outputed.

I wish that if test_2 were failed , output report.html and log.html of test_1 and test_2(Interim report), and pybot continue to execute test_3.

Is any idea of grant my wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get what you want. Robot keeps the report in memory and only writes it to disk when the entire test run is completed.

You can create a listener that will give you the same information that is in the report if you wish, and you can use that to write your own file. Or, you can create a custom script that runs each suite separately, and then combines all of the individual reports after all of the tests have run.

Comment: Your answer is very easy to understand. I try to create script to execute test separately , and merge it. Thank you very much!